# Improve XGBoostRegression predictions when high volatility

Tags: regression, cart, boosting

I am using boosted trees via XGBoostRegressor in SKLearn to predict values of a time serie.

I get a quite good predictions when values range is close to the mean, however if I suddenly have high volatility, ie values far from the mean, my accuracy decreases and my predictions are always lower (ie it doesn't manage to predict the peak, always smoothing it).

What are my alternatives to improve this?

EDIT: here is an example of result I guess. Actual values (blue) and predictions (green)

[image: Dataset + predictions]

Comment: Interesting question, but please post the data. – *Reviewer*

Comment: Added a graph to support the question :) can't share more than that unfortunately

Comment: Wrt the data: you could scale the y-values and add a small noise term to them, and/or shift the time stamps. This way, you won't be sharing the true data. Domain knowledge is going to be an important factor here: What are you predicting? Which predictors are you including now? E.g. maybe you just need to include a Saturday dummy to capture some of the spikes.